# Python multiprocessing second process doesn't start

Tags: python, concurrency, multiprocessing

Hello I am trying to run 2 functions at the same time in python. Both read data from 2 separate meters over USB and they are not dependant on each other. I have tried multiprocessing but the second meter never starts.

```
def readMeter1():
   while True:
       #read Meter1

def readMeter2():
   while True:
       #read Meter2

if __name__ == "__main__":
Process(target = readMeter1()).start()
Process(target = readMeter2()).start()
```

Comment: It should be `Process(target=readMeter1)`, not `Process(target=readMeter1())`. Same for `readMeter2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter `target` must be something callable (a function, in your case). You don't need to call that function yourself, `start()` will do it after launching a new process:

```
Process(target=readMeter1).start()  # fork a new process, call readMeter1
Process(target=readMeter2).start()  # fork a new process, call readMeter2
```

Because you call `readMeter1`, it starts an infinite loop in the current process and blocks everything else.